# Darkening quad to simulate AO

Tags: glsl

I want to make a color darker based on a occlusion factor I calculate on my map, I need it to simulate AO, I thought about blending the face with a specified dark color texture as a one of the possible solutions, I am wondering if  there is anything I can do without using textures.
Actually the engine is minecraft like and I calculate the occlusion factor based on the voxels surroundings the face I am taking in consideration.
I am not looking for a complicated method because is only the first implementation.
cheers

I need a very simple effect right now, ssao is out of the question for many reasons. I think
the only solution is to color the vertices but how can I do it in a way that the face does not look completely black?

What do you think about the second solution to blend a texture with the quad color?
In "Graphics Setting 1" = vertex coloring and "Graphics Setting 2" = texture blending.

Comment: have you looked into Screen Space AO? it's not that hard to implement. other than that you are only left with coloring the vertices, but then the quality would depend on your geometry.

Comment: You don't need blending. just draw your quad with texture and also pass the color. glColor3f(0, 0, 0) would make it completely dark and glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5) would make it half dark.